# Design for storing recent actions and recently met people

Tags: database, database-design

I was wondering how to set up a database for storing actions people recently done when they travel. For example, if they go to a museum, the database will store this text "Bob went to this museum" and store the user id and timestamp. I was wondering if these events should be stored in just one table, and if I want the events of a single person I will just query this table with a user id.

On a similar note I want to store 50 users the user has "recently met" meaning the last 50 users the userhas been around in their travels. I was thinking this could be stored in one table as well, with just user IDs being paired with no duplicates. I'm just afraid the table might get too big.

Any suggestions on table set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would go with an ER structure like this:

[image: ER Diagram]